# Firebase functions result in android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to show the result of **firebase function** in the android application .
It is my first function to practice .I deployed my function **correctly** and works fine in console. then the next step I want is: how to show the result of my function in an empty activity of **Android**?? or what are steps to connect between functions and android app
 this is my simple  function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
 });
```

Comment: You should probably be using HTTPS callable functions in your app.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Answer (score 3):

To communicate with firebase http cloud function from android app, you need to use any http client library like OkHttp.

You can get the URL of your cloud function from firebase console.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            HttpUrl.Builder httpBuider =
                    HttpUrl.parse(FIREBASE_CLOUD_FUNCTION_URL).newBuilder();

            Request request = new Request.Builder().
                    url(httpBuider.build()).build();

            httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "error in getting response from firebase cloud function");
                }
                @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response){
                    ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                    String resp = "";
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "fail response from firebase cloud function");
                    }else {
            Log.e(TAG, "respone "+resp);
                    }

                }
            });
    }
```

For complete example, see [firebase cloud functions example](http://www.zoftino.com/android-server-side-functionality-using-firebase-cloud-functions)